# How can I check if a single equation with two variables can be solved with only integers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How can I take a single equation, $k = \frac{132-n}{6n+1}$ and check if $k$ and $n$ can be solved as integers?

In this example, it's relatively easy to figure out by inspection that $k = 10$ and $n =2$, but for others, such as $\frac{100-n}{6n+1}$, there is no integer answers. Now I don't need to actually solve for $k$ and $n$, I just need to know if it's possible to get integer solutions for any given equation.

It also might be important to note that $k$ must be greater than or equal to $1$, so $n$ must be less than $132$ or $100$ depending on the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such equations are know as [Diophantine Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20Diophantine%20equation,monomials%2C%20each%20of%20degree%20one.) where we are interested only in the integer solutions.

One of the ways to solve such questions is by using the property that:

***If $HCF(a,b)=c$ then $c$ can be expressed as a linear combination of a and b.***

Now, let's convert you equation in a form where we can apply this property as follows:
$$k=\frac{132-n}{6n+1}$$
$$\Rightarrow 6kn+k+n=132$$
$$\Rightarrow kn+k/6+n/6=22$$
$$\Rightarrow (k+1/6)(n+1/6)=22+1/36$$
$$\Rightarrow (6k+1)(6n+1)=793=1\times 793=13\times 61 $$
Thus, we get $$(k,n)=(0,132),(2,10),(132,0),(10,2)$$

Similarly using the same approach we can also find the solutions for the next equation.
$$k=\frac{100-n}{6n+1}$$
$$\Rightarrow 6kn+k+n=100$$
$$\Rightarrow kn+k/6+n/6=100/6$$
$$\Rightarrow (k+1/6)(n+1/6)=100/6+1/36$$
$$\Rightarrow (6k+1)(6n+1)=601=1\times 601 $$
Thus, we get $$(k,n)=(0,100),(100,0)$$

To cross-check that we indeed have integer solutions for the above equation, [see this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integer+solutions%3A+k%3D%28100-n%29%2F%286n%2B1%29).

***But kindly see the below variant:***
$$(6k+1)(6n+1)=445=1\times 445 = 5\times 89$$
This will give you wrong results as in after this you will **not** have ***all*** the **integer solutions**. We need to **consider** the **negative factors** too. Luckily, in the above examples the negative factors didn't return any integer solution.

So, we proceed as follows:
$$(6k+1)(6n+1)=445=1\times 445 = 5\times 89 = \boldsymbol{-1\times -445 = -5\times -89}$$
Thus, we get $$(k,n)=(0,74),(74,0), \boldsymbol{(-1,-15),(-15,-1)}$$

Hope this way you can solve other variants of these questions.

Answer (score 0):

Noodle:

$k = \frac {132-n}{6n+1}$

$6k = \frac {6\cdot 132 - 6n}{6n+1} =\frac {6\cdot 132 + 1 - (6n+1)}{6n+1}= \frac {793}{6n+1} -1$.

So $6n+1|793=13\cdot 61$ so we have $6n+1 = \pm 1,\pm 13,\pm 61,\pm 793$

So $6n = (\pm 1 - 1), (\pm 13 - 1), (\pm 61 - 1), (\pm 793 - 1)$ but $6|6n$ so we must have those terms all be multiples of $6$.

So $6n = 0, 12, 60, 792$ and $n = 0,2, 10, 132$.

And $6k= \frac {793}{6n+1} -1= \frac {793}{1,13,61,793}-1=792, 60,12,0$ all of which are divisible by $6$ so

If $n=0,2,10,132$ then $k = 132,10,2,0$.